# Has Forky's personality changed between "Toy Story 4" and "Forky Asks A Question"?

Tags: pixar, toy-story, toy-story-4, forky-asks-a-question

In the new TV Show "Forky Asks A Question", Forky seems to have severe ADHD. He can't focus for more than two seconds, and interrupts each conversation with comments unrelated to the question at hand.

Did Forky display these characteristics in "Toy Story 4" as well? I recall he was very inquisitive, but did he have such a short attention span in the movie too?

Comment: Only in regards to trash, and that largely early on.

Answer (score 1):

## Forky grew as a character over the course of the movie

Initially Forky has a very simplistic view of himself. He refers to himself as "trash" (the first few scenes involve Woody trying to convince him he's now a toy) and behaves like (more or less) a 4-year-old child. As the movie goes on, Forky becomes more articulate. We first see this when

> he throws himself out of the RV

Woody then tells him his own story about Andy and we see a more dynamic Forky by the end of the movie (to the point he is now playing the role Woody played for a new plastic knife toy).

## The shorts seem to show middle-movie Forky

Around the time of the spoiler above, Forky could talk, but was more like a 6-year-old now. Still spastic, but able to articulate thoughts without being considerate of what was going on around him.